# Not able to get post data from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I really need your help guys. I am not able to access post data in php from ajax. I have no idea what's going on here. I tried searching for solutions in stackoverflow but none of them helped me. Here is my script,..

```
    <script>
                    $('form.ajax').on('submit',function() {
                        var that = $(this),
                        url = that.attr('action'),
                        type = that.attr('method'),
                        data = {};

                        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
                            var that = $(this),
                            name = that.attr('name'),
                            value = that.val();

                            data[name] = value;
                            console.log(data.name);
                        });
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: type,
                            data: data,
                            success: function(response) {

                            }

                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                </script>
```

here is my php code,

```
                  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed to connect to MySQL:"+mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Invoice";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$myQuery);
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceNumber LIKE '%".$name."'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
$data1 = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $row_data = array(
        'InvoiceNumber' => $row['InvoiceNumber'],
        'InvoicePONumber' => $row['InvoicePONumber']
    );
    array_push($data1,$row_data);
}

echo json_encode($data1);
```

?>

Comment: Make it a habit to remove login credentials from your code before posting. You don't want others to take advantage of that.

Comment: Glad to see you are using code academy's script for this. I use it all the time, saves code writing

Comment: Why are you trying to get post data? Why not put the post data into the database table them get it out?

Answer (score 2):

The default request method for `$.ajax` is GET, so you will never get any results in `$_POST` var. instead you should use `$.post` or add the request type to your `ajax` call.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: In this script, the type is being picked up by the form php. Whatever is the method in the form opening is what is reflected here.